# how do i alternate from positive int and negative int in a number sequence

Tags: java

I am doing an assignment for university and I have to print out the first ten numbers of a number sequence which is 1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4, -2.... I have worked out the rest of the sequence which is where you alternate adding a positive number and then a negative one for example to go from 1 to 2 you add the number one and then to go from 2 to 0  you add the number -2. But I cant quite get my head around how to alternate from positive to negative using just a simple `while` loop.
I dont want this to be solved for me I just want for someone to tell me how I would alternate the positive and negative ints.
Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: One way is just to multiply by -1.  -1 times a positive is a negative, and -1 times a negative is a positive.

Comment: I would use a boolean variable which alternates in each call of the loop. Then check it. One time u add a number, the other time u substract it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting the code. The idea is to swap between the negative and positive multiplier after each step in while cycle.

```
int precision = 10;
int i = 0;
int lastNum = 1;
boolean switcher = false;
while (i++ <= precision) {
    System.out.println(lastNum);
    lastNum += (switcher = !switcher) ? i : -i;
}
```

```js
var precision = 10;
var i = 0;
var lastNum = 1;
var switcher = false;
while (i++ <= precision) {
  console.log(lastNum);
  lastNum += (switcher = !switcher) ? i : -i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a straightforward arithmetic problem.

```
1 + 1 is 2.
2 - 2 is 0.
0 + 3 is 3.
3 - 4 is -1.
-1 + 5 is 4.
```

From there, the pattern is fairly straightforward - the addend (the second number you're adding) increments from 1 to 5, but it has alternating signs.  The augend (the first number you're adding) starts at 1 but is the result of the previous sums.

Multiplying the addend by -1 in a loop would be a start; I leave this as an exercise for the reader (as the hard part - determining the algorithm - has been explained above).

Comment: int counter = 1;
    while (counter<=6){
     counter*=-1;
     System.out.print(counter+",");
     counter++;   // something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The Maths are :

> f(x) = 1+x/2 if x is even
>
> f(x) = (3-x)/2 if x is odd

So you can simply do this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int desiredLength = 10;
    for (int i =1; i<=desiredLength; i++)
        System.out.println(i+" : "+myFunction(i);
}

public static int myFunction(int x){
    return (x%2==1?(3-x)/2:1+x/2);
}
```